# replacement of header file iostream.h in c

Tags: c

i don't know the header file in c as iostream.h in c++

Comment: I don't think that it is a replacement, but if you want common I/O, you need `stdio.h`

Comment: By the way, in C++ it's `<iostream>`, **not** `<iostream.h>`.

Comment: Bello vedere un altro italiano da queste parti! ;)

Comment: @BlackBear: nome e cognome mi tradiscono, credo che ce ne siano tanti non così riconoscibili :)

Comment: Guarderò in futuro, ma non penso che questo sia un paese di programmatori..

Answer (score 6):

IO streams are specific for C++ and cannot be implemented in C in the same way.

The way of performing input/output operations in C is to use functions from `stdio.h` header, like `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

There is, obviously, no direct replacement but stdio.h does a lot of similar things ...